# Ping works only if triggered from one side

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking

I have two devices, ostensibly on the same network using a NB604N Modem Router, but one connected wirelessly, and the other, wired. Both have addresses and both can access the internet with no issue.

Unfortunately, I can't ping from the wired-connected device to the other one on the onset. If I trigger a ping from the wireless device to the wired device, this works fine, and after this happens, I can start pinging from the wired device to the wireless device as well.

Is this due to some fault with my router, which seems to have some sort of wired/wireless bridged network? Or could it be something else?

Comment: Exactly what commands are you using, and what are the responses?  I.E. are you using hostnames or IP addresses?  Describe these *"devices"*; what OS is involved?

Comment: Wired device: 192.168.1.10/24 (Ubuntu Server 18); Wireless device: 192.168.1.4/24 (Win 10/Android). Pinging (just `ping`) 192.168.1.10 from 192.168.1.4 doesn't work; but if I do the opposite it works. After this though, pinging 192.168.1.10 from 192.168.1.4 magically starts working. The fail responses are `Destination host unreachable`. However though, both devices can ping 8.8.8.8 just fine.

Comment: Firewall is off on both ends.